# Simplest way to split a csv string into an array that works for both bash & zsh

Tags: arrays, string, bash, split, zsh

What is the simplest way to split a csv string into an array using only builtins that works for both bash & zsh?

I have separate code that works for bash and for zsh, but I haven't yet found anything that works for both:

```sh
csv='a,b,c'

# Works in zsh, but not in bash
array=(${(s:,:)csv})

# Works in bash, but not in zsh
array=(${csv//,/ }) # This requires that $IFS contains the space character
```

Comment: To avoid unquoted expansions, the Bash method should really be `IFS=, read -a array <<< "$csv"` – no clue if that works in zsh.

Comment: in `zsh` it would be `IFS=, read -rA arr <<< "$csv"`

Comment: Ah well – should still be that for the Bash version anyway ;)

Comment: @XDR : Why do you want to write code which works the same for two fairly different programming languages? Your code will most likely reside in a script, which designates (via the #! line) whether it is bash or zsh, i.e. it's not going to be sourced, isn't it? I don't see the point in forcing the program to be able to run on both shells.

Comment: It will be sourced.  The existing code is compatible with both bash & zsh, so I must keep it compatible.  It's not my decision to make.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there are two nearly identical commands, one for each shell.

```
# bash
IFS=, read -ra array <<< "$csv"

# zsh
IFS=, read -rA array <<< "$csv"
```

The syntax is the same; the only difference is whether you use `a` or `A` as the option to `read`. I would recommend adding a conditional statement that detects which shell is executing the script, then use a variable to store the correct option.

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    arr_opt=a
elif [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
    arr_opt=A
fi

IFS=, read -r"$arr_opt" array <<< "$csv"
```

Checking for non-empty version parameters isn't foolproof, but it should be good enough.

Comment: `IFS=, read -r"${BASH_VERSION:+a}${ZSH_VERSION:+A}" array <<< "$csv"` :D

Comment: True :) But I'd rather key the sniffing logic separate from the business logic. There might be other shell-specific differences you need to account for, which could all be set in a single `if` statement at the start of the script.